# Styling not working in all text view in react native

Tags: react-native

Below is the code snippet of my screen, styling is working perfectly on 2 text views but not on the last one. Can anyone help me?

```
<View style={styles.userInfo}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.postCount}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Posts</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{formatNumber(this.state.data.followersCount)}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Followers</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text styles={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.followingCount}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Following</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Gallery items={this.state.data.images} />
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra s in the last text style

try this

```
<View style={styles.userInfo}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.postCount}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Posts</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{formatNumber(this.state.data.followersCount)}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Followers</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.followingCount}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Following</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Gallery items={this.state.data.images} />
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo, `styles`, first `Text`

```
 <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text styles={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.followingCount}</Text>
          <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Following</Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakenly wrote styles instead of style i.e.:

```
<Text **styles**={[header3,styles.space,baseColor]}>{this.state.data.followingCount}</Text>
      <Text style={[secondary1, hintColor]}>Following</Text>
    </View>
```

Comment: I corrected the mistake,now it is showing error 500. Do you know something about this?

Comment: I don't have any idea for now